# Problema en Angular: Redirección a /login al borrar token JWT y problemas con guardián de ruta

Tags: angular, jwt, redirección, autenticación, guards

Me asignaron la tarea de implementar una funcionalidad en un sistema desarrollado en Angular versión 13. La funcionalidad consiste en obtener la URL a la que se dirige el usuario, lo cual es útil para redirigir al usuario a esa URL después de iniciar sesión. Sin embargo, noté que el sistema me redirige al login cuando el token JWT de autenticación no existe en el local storage. Entonces, comencé a buscar guardianes de rutas, pero solo encontré uno, el cual está insertado en la ruta de login. En las demás rutas, no existe ningún guardian.

**auth.services**

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Role, User, UserResponse } from 'src/app/shared/models/user.interface';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertHelper } from 'src/app/shared/components/helpers/alert.helpers';
import { interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
const helper = new JwtHelperService();

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  tiempo: Subscription;
  redirectURL: string;
  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private role = new BehaviorSubject<Role>("NULL");
  public userName = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  public NombreUsuario: string = ""

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private alert: AlertHelper) {
      this.checkToken();
      this.ObtenerinfoToken();
      this.tiempo = interval(200000).subscribe((x => {

        // funcion que se ejecuta cada x tiempo
        //coloca aca las futuras comprovaciones con tiempo
        // console.log("se ejecuta la funcion");

        if (!this.checkToken()) {
          this.redirectURL = this.router.url;
          this.router.navigate(['login'], { replaceUrl: true })
        };

      }))
  }

  get isLogged(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  }

  get ObtenerNombre(): string {
    return this.NombreUsuario;
  }

  get isAdmin(): Observable<string> {
    return this.role.asObservable();
  }

  login(authData: User): Observable<UserResponse> {
    return this.http
      .post<UserResponse>(`${environment.API}/rrhh/usuario/login`, authData)
      .pipe(
        map((res: UserResponse) => {

          const tokeninfo = helper.decodeToken(res.token)
          this.NombreUsuario = tokeninfo.user.nombre
          this.saveToken(res.token)
          this.loggedIn.next(true)

          this.role.next(tokeninfo.user.rol)
          return res
        }),
        catchError((err) => this.handlerError(err))
      );
  }

  logout(): void {
    localStorage.clear();
    this.loggedIn.next(false);
    this.router.navigate(['login'], { replaceUrl: true });
  }

  private checkToken(): boolean {

    let userToken = localStorage.getItem('token') || null;

    if (userToken) {

      const isExpired = helper.isTokenExpired(userToken);
      const tokeninfo = helper.decodeToken(userToken);
      if (isExpired) {
        userToken = ''
        this.logout()
        return false;
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('rol', tokeninfo.user.rol);
        this.loggedIn.next(true);
        this.role.next(tokeninfo.user.rol)
        return true
      }
    }
    else {
      return false
    }
  }

  private saveToken(token: string): void {

    localStorage.setItem('token', token);

  }

  public isLoggin(){
    return localStorage.getItem('token') === null || localStorage.getItem('token').length > 0;
  }

  public ObtenerinfoToken(){
    let userToken = localStorage.getItem('token') || null;
    if (userToken){
       const tokeninfo = helper.decodeToken(userToken);
       this.NombreUsuario = tokeninfo.user.nombre;
       return tokeninfo.user;


    }
    else {
      this.logout();
    }
  }

  private handlerError(err: any): Observable<never> {
    let errorMessage = "Ha ocurrido un error recibiendo la data";
    if (err) {
      errorMessage = `Error: ${err.error.msg}`;
    }
    this.alert.error_small(errorMessage);
    return throwError(err.message);
  }

  esEmailValido(email: string): boolean {
    let mailValido = false;
    'use strict';
    var EMAIL_REGEX = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/;
    if (email.match(EMAIL_REGEX)) {
      mailValido = true;
    }
    return mailValido;
  }
}
```

**app-routing.module**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CheckLoginGuard } from './shared/guards/check-login.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule) },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/auth/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule),
canActivate:[CheckLoginGuard] }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**home-routing.module**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

**login-routing.module**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: LoginComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LoginRoutingModule { }
```

El guardián es este, pero su lógica es si deja pasar al login o no.

**check-login.guard**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/pages/auth/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CheckLoginGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth_service: AuthService){

  }
  canActivate():Observable<boolean>{

    //este guaerd permite acceder a la ruta seleccionada si no esta logeado
    return this.auth_service.isLogged.pipe(
      take(1),
      map((isLogged: boolean)=>!isLogged)
    );
  }
  
}
```

**PROBLEMA**

Al borrar mi token JWT de autenticación en el local storage y dirigirme a cualquier URL, me redirige a /login y no llega ni siquiera a ejecutar el componente, y tampoco el guardián que añadí como prueba a la ruta /admin.

Hice una prueba, quitandole el guardian a la ruta del login y sigue redirigiendome a la ruta del login cuando no tengo el token.

Además, realicé pruebas en mi backend, donde se verifica el token JWT, pero solo se ejecuta cuando se hace una petición, es decir, desde un interceptor. Sin embargo, este, al igual que los guardianes de ruta, no se alcanzan a ejecutar.

¿Será que angular tiene alguna capa que se configura o algún archivo que se configura para este tipo de casos?.

Comment: 2 cosas: 1. En las rutas, los path que van en blanco `''` siempre van después de los que tienen valores y antes de los que tienen wildcards. 2. ¿Cómo podemos solucionar y/o realizar una opinión sin el código del servicio del `auth_service` ? Edita la pregunta y agrega esa información. Saludos :D

Comment: Tome en consideración tus puntos, ya edite la pregunta y agregue el auth.services.